# Using ? in a list argument

Tags: java

I am trying to add a CustomObject to a list of CustomObject (that is encapsulated in an other class, CustomObjectList).
However, I have the following error on my console :

> The method .add(CustomObject) in the Type CustomObjectList is not applicable for the argument (capture#5-of ? extends ICustomObject).

`ICustomObject`is the interface implemented by CustomObject.

`CustomObjectList` is implemented as follows :

```
class CustomObjectList {
    private List<CustomObject> bar = new ArrayList<CustomObject>();

    public List<CustomObject> getCustomObjectList() {
        return this.bar;
    }

    public void add(CustomObject foo) {
        this.bar.add(foo);
    }
}
```

The code raising the error message is as follows :

```
CustomObjectList randomName = new CustomObjectList();
for (ICustomObject iCO : anOtherObject.getCustomObjectList()) {
    randomName.add(iCO);
}
```

With :

```
public class anOtherObject {
    private CustomObjectList customObjectList;
    public List<? extends ICustomObject> getCustomObjectList {
        return customObjectList.getCustomObjectList();
    }
}
```

Does anyone understand what seems to be the problem? I am quite at a loss here. I know !, are supposed to be generics but I do not understand how it works...

Comment: Please edit your question to show what `ICustomObject` is and how it relates to everything else. Also, your error seems to arise from another piece of code which calls your `add` method, but you haven't shown that code either.

Comment: I am most sorry, I am working on some code from my company and I posted this partially by memory. I edited as you asked.

Comment: ***You*** defined `CustomObjectList#getCustomObjectList()` to return `List<CustomObject>` and in `anOtherObject#getCustomObjectList()` you pretend it returns `List<? extends ICustomObject>` ... why?

Comment: It is not my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface returns a list of objects that implement ICustomObject but those objects might not be of class CustomObject (since other classes might also implement ICustomObject) and because of that you can't add those returned items into a list of CustomObjects.

Comment: It depends, for example you could define bar as  List<ICustomObject> or cast the ICustomObjects that are of class CustomObject before adding them to the list